# NSCache not thread safe in swift code?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure if this thread unsafe in Swift,Output should be 31 characters, is such that NSCache isn't thread safe?

```
let nscache = NSCache()
nscache.setObject("", forKey: "1")

let globalQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)
dispatch_async(globalQueue) {
    print(NSThread.currentThread())

    for i in 0...10 {

        let str = nscache.objectForKey("1") as! String + ".\(i)"
        nscache.setObject(str, forKey: "1")
        print("str:\(str)")
    }
}

dispatch_async(globalQueue) {
    print(NSThread.currentThread())

    for i in 11...20 {

        let str = nscache.objectForKey("1") as! String + ".\(i)"
        nscache.setObject(str, forKey: "1")
        print("str:\(str)")
    }
}

dispatch_async(globalQueue) {
    print(NSThread.currentThread())

    for i in 21...30 {

        let str = nscache.objectForKey("1") as! String + ".\(i)"
        nscache.setObject(str, forKey: "1")
        print("str:\(str)")
    }
}
```

Output

> /////////////////print/////////////////
>
> str:.21 str:.21.11 str:.21.11.0 str:.21.11.0.22 str:.21.11.0.22.12
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1 str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13 str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.24
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2 str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.14
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.25 str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15 str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.5
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.29
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7.19
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7.19.30
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7.19.30.8
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7.19.30.8.20
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7.19.30.8.20.9
>   str:.21.11.0.22.12.1.23.13.2.3.15.26.4.16.27.17.6.28.18.7.19.30.8.20.9.10

Comment: You have three async operations all updating the same key at the same time. The order in which that occurs is fundamentally undefined between the three. If you look at the last str output though you can see that the numbers are properly ordered within their operation, e.g. ... 1 ... 2 ... 3 ... 4, and so on. I think that NSCache is doing an admirable job here.

Comment: If you want to control the order of async operations then take a look at NSOperationQueue or (if you really want to use GCD) then the dispatch queue equivalent.

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the thread-safety of NSCache. Between retrieving a value and setting the new value, one of the other dispatched blocks  can have updated the value in the mean-time.

Comment: How do I do to verify NSCache is thread-safe? Use the code